# How to show meta tags to View Page Source, added through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, seo

Our website is built in pure HTML format and we have made an API which is built in node framework and we are calling it using javascript in HTML.

The issue is our Meta Tags are coming up from API itself (AJAX)  and it's getting added to the HTML DOM successfully but not showing in Page View Source, and as per Semrush helpdesk, the Meta Tags must show in Page View Source to get it Crawled by the bots.

I am confused what to do with it.

Comment: Why are the meta tags added to the HTML by the API on the frontend and not by the node server on the backend?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier We are adding the meta tags from backend only. But on HTML frontend, we are calling the API using ajax.

Comment: If the meta tags are added in the backend, then the HTML served by the backend already has the meta tags in there, no? Or do you mean that the backend serves the HTML without content and the content is added through JavaScript when the page loads?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - Yes exactly, the page content is added through the JavaScript when the page loads. The HTML page is already created and the content getting loaded into it.

Comment: This is a very common issue with frontend rendering. The solution lies in the backend. If you need to have meta tags on view source, then the server should send them in the HTML. You should look into Isomorphic JavaScript. It means that when you open the page the server renders everything (including content and meta tags) without any help of JavaScript on the frontend. All other requests that occur through clicking links on the page are handled by the frontend by making calls to the API.